# How to modify <script type="text/x-magento-templ">?

Tags: magento2, javascript, template

I'm looking for a way to modify the default dehavior of a select template.

I just want to add a button and keeping what's already done by magento team. So, I copied the template select.phtml in my extension but it is a "text/x-magento-template" and not a "text/x-magento-init". And I found very few resources about this javascript templating system.

I tried that in a test.js:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $("input[id^='btn-test']").click( function () {
         console.log('click');
    });
});
```

And this is my select.phtml :

```
<h1>Template test</h1>
<input type="button" id="btn-test-1" value="OK" /> 
<script id="custom-option-select-type-template" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <div id="product_option_<%- data.option_id %>_type_<%- data.group %>" class="fieldset">
        <input type="button" id="btn-test-2" value="OK" /> 
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
   "*": {
     "HappyDev_Test/test": {}
   }
}
</script>
```

Clicking the first button works as expected but the one in the javascript template doesn't produce anything.

How can I do to insert my own code in the javascript template ?

Comment: Not sure that duplicate IDs will work in this scenario even if this is plain HTML. Try using classes for jquery targeting instead

Comment: The problem doesn't come from the duplicate ID. I updated the code to avoid it and still have the same problem.

Comment: In fact, in need to add my own javascript in the Underscore.js template. But no success until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code bind the click event only to the elements that exist at the time of binding. Replace your `test.js` code with below one:

```
require(['jquery'], function ($) {
    $(document).on("click","input[id^='btn-test']", function () {
         console.log('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: It works. But I'm not really sure why.

Comment: Because when you bind click event, it bind the click event only to the elements that exist at the time of binding. See [this blog](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-bind-onclick-event-to-dynamically-added-elements-in-jquery.php) for more detail about event binding for dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this javascript code
You can define underscore library as well below

```
require(['jquery','jquery/ui','underscore','mage/template'], function ($, jqui, _, mageTemplate) {
    $("#btn-test").on("click", function () {
        console.log('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have the same result.

Comment: I'm still reading the underscoreJS doc but I don't understand how and where the "<%- data.something %>" is built.

Comment: clear js in pub/static and re-deploy for update any changed.
M2 use underscore for migrate PrototypeJS to jquery . It quitely helpful and mageTemplate for bind dynamic data inside template. I not get clear about this much

Comment: I cleared the code and changed the "console.log('click')" in "console.log('test2')" to be sure that the new version was running. I just checked the code again and run another test but I have the same result: the button in the x-magento-template doesn't trigger the console.log().

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved but was not linked to my initial question.

I post here the solution found for this question :

> the template

```
<!-- <?php var_dump($this->customData); ?> -->
<input type="button" id="btn-mage" value="Test magento" />
<script type="text/x-magnento-template" id="mage-template">
        <ul id="<%- data.id %>">
                <li>Name: <%- data.name %></li>
                <li>Location: <%- data.location %></li>
        </ul>
</script>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
        "*": {
                "HappyDev_Test/test": {}
       }
 }
</script>
```

> and the JS :

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn-mage", function () {
         var tmpl = mageTemplate('#mage-template');
         var data = {
                 data: {
                         name: 'John',
                         location: 'New York'
                 }
         };
         $('#target').after(
                 tmpl(data)
         );
});
```

I'm still trying to find a way to load data from a PHP Block in my magento script template.I'd appreciate if somebody has a clue how to do that.

Comment: you should post new question for this, as this was not related to your previous question.