# How to add a custom parameter in javascript template?

Tags: magento2, template

I'm working on the javascript templating system. I successfully created an x-magento-template ([see here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/108269/37416))

But I still don't understand how magento work with it internaly.

My template looks like that :

```
<script id="custom-option-select-type-row-template" type="text/x-magento-tmpl">
    <% console.log(data) %>
</script>
```

And produce this result :

> Object { id: "1", option_type_id: -1, select_id: 1, sku: "", price: "" }

The script as the id of an existing template in Magento\Catalog module.

I didn't find in magento code any :

> mageTemplate("#custom-option-select-type-row-template");

So, how magento can fill the "data" object and find the template to call ?

I want to be able to add my own parameter in this object.

Answer (score 0):

Magento use `mageTemplate` component. 
See it in

> lib\web\mage\template.js

to parse template inside script type `text/x-magento-template` with `underscore` lib helps

Data stored in `input` hidden somewhere used to pass through template

Comment: All I see in the template.js is the return function taking tmpl and data in parameter. That means there is another component in charge of finding the script id and parsing its content.  By the way I would appreciate if you could give me a basic example of the use of the `input type hidden` in order to retrieve information in the template. I had no success with it.